# How to minimise the time for new static content to appear on the GitHub Pages CDN?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

Assume we are only pushing lightweight static content like small HTML or JS files with no Liquid tags.  There are no plugins, and there is no _posts/ directory, and files are never changed once committed.

Because nothing really needs to be built, in theory if we configure `incremental_build: true` and `keep_files: ['.html', '.js']`, then the build should be very fast.

However, right now, the GitHub pages build only happens every 5 minutes or so, so effectively there is a lag of 0 to 10 minutes.

[image]

Is there a way to reduce the time it takes for the file to appear at [repo].github.io/[path]?  Is there some logic to it, for example do more commits or more files or more reads have an effect one way or another?

Answer (score 1):

Github Pages does not respect those options. You could try prebuilding your site, but will possibly increase the total time to deploy. It's also possible that the build is happening instantly but it's taking time for the CDN to receive updates and invalidate caches.

You can try using another host (like running your own Jekyll server on EC2) or having your build upload the static content to S3 instead.

However, I recommend taking a step back and asking why you need less than 10 minute latency on deploy. If there are highly volatile resources you need to serve, then perhaps you need to identify those and serve them in a different way. Static site generators are good at, well, static content, not so much for highly volatile content.

If the volatile resources are page content, then it sounds like you have a use case better served with a mainstream CMS like Wordpress. If it's code, then deploy that separately to S3 and reference it in your site.

Comment: *Github Pages does not respect those options.*  Thank you.  For others: https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-jekyll/#configuration-settings-you-cannot-change  But should `keep_files` not work?  And `limit_posts`?

Comment: *It's also possible that the build is happening instantly.*  In the commits tab, there is a green checkmark / red x next to commits that built (successfully / unsuccessfully).  Added a screenshot.

Comment: *why you need less than 10 minute latency* It is not an absolute requirement.